# type signature between function and class

Tags: haskell

```
data Maybe' a = Nothing' | Just' a deriving (Show)

class From' t 
    where from' :: t a -> a

instance From' Maybe' 
    where from' (Just' x) = x
```

This works.

But...

```
from2 :: t a -> a 
from2 (Just' x)  = x

Couldn't match type `t' with `Maybe''
  `t' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for from2 :: t a -> a at test.hs:11:1
In the pattern: Just' x
In an equation for `from2': from2 (Just' x) = x
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the instance, `t` is defined to be `Maybe'`, so `from'` has to have type `Maybe' a -> a`. If you write:

```
from2 :: Maybe' a -> a
```

then it'll work. The error message is saying that your type signature claims that `from2` could turn `t a` into `a` for *any* choice of `t`, but your definition only works if `t` is `Maybe'`.

By the way, this function is already defined for the standard `Maybe` type as [`fromJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v%3afromJust) in the `Data.Maybe` module, but you probably shouldn't use it, since it'll give an unhelpful error message if you ever pass it `Nothing`. Of course, if it's just an example, then that's fine.

Comment: No problem :) If my answer helped you, you should click the check mark next to it, so that the question is marked as solved.

Comment: @ehird: the type he's using is `Maybe'`, not `Maybe`. You should correct your answer adding the missing `'` :)